# Why doesn't the sub-resource have an index?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a routing file like this in Rails 5.2:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :posts do
    resource :comments
  end

  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

Why isn't there a `/posts/:post_id/comments` route to list all the comments (`comments#index`) for that post? and a `/posts/:post_id/comments/:id` route to show a single specific comment. The routes look like this:

```
>rake routes
                   Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                                                              Controller#Action
        new_post_comments GET    /posts/:post_id/comments/new(.:format)                                                   comments#new
       edit_post_comments GET    /posts/:post_id/comments/edit(.:format)                                                  comments#edit
            post_comments GET    /posts/:post_id/comments(.:format)                                                       comments#show
                          PATCH  /posts/:post_id/comments(.:format)                                                       comments#update
                          PUT    /posts/:post_id/comments(.:format)                                                       comments#update
                          DELETE /posts/:post_id/comments(.:format)                                                       comments#destroy
                          POST   /posts/:post_id/comments(.:format)                                                       comments#create
                    posts GET    /posts(.:format)                                                                         posts#index
                          POST   /posts(.:format)                                                                         posts#create
                 new_post GET    /posts/new(.:format)                                                                     posts#new
                edit_post GET    /posts/:id/edit(.:format)                                                                posts#edit
                     post GET    /posts/:id(.:format)                                                                     posts#show
                          PATCH  /posts/:id(.:format)                                                                     posts#update
                          PUT    /posts/:id(.:format)                                                                     posts#update
                          DELETE /posts/:id(.:format)                                                                     posts#destroy
       rails_service_blob GET    /rails/active_storage/blobs/:signed_id/*filename(.:format)                               active_storage/blobs#show
rails_blob_representation GET    /rails/active_storage/representations/:signed_blob_id/:variation_key/*filename(.:format) active_storage/representations#show
       rails_disk_service GET    /rails/active_storage/disk/:encoded_key/*filename(.:format)                              active_storage/disk#show
update_rails_disk_service PUT    /rails/active_storage/disk/:encoded_token(.:format)                                      active_storage/disk#update
     rails_direct_uploads POST   /rails/active_storage/direct_uploads(.:format)                                           active_storage/direct_uploads#create
```

Is this a change since Rails 4.2? This is my first time playing with 5.2 and most of my experience was before 3.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why isn't there a /posts/:post_id/comments route

There is:

```
post_comments GET    /posts/:post_id/comments(.:format)        comments#show
```

> [Why isn't there] a /posts/:post_id/comments/:id route to show a single specific comment

Because you've used `resource` (singular) for `comments`, which says there are not multiple comments. It seems like you want `resources :comments` instead.

Comment: The full phrase is: Why isn't there a /posts/:post_id/comments route to list all the comments (comments#index) for that post.